# windows 7 - set printer offline

Tags: windows-7, printing, print-spooler

I am working on an application that prints large reports. Is there a way to set a printer offline so the report pages remain in the print-spool?

I have looked through all of the Printer Properties and Properties (right-clicked on printer in Devices and Printers) to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the printer and select 'See what's printing'

Then select 'Pause Printing' from the Printer menu.

Answer (score 0):

The spool should give you priority until the job is complete. Are other people kicking your job out of the queue?

Comment: No. I am the only user, but as soon as print the report from my application (VB.NET) the report goes directly to the printer. I want it to stay in the print queue.

Comment: What is the purpose of keeping it in the queue?

Answer (score 0):

To keep the job in the queue listing after it's been printed, go to Printer Properties. Click the Advanced tab and tick "Keep printed document"

To stop printing, select the printer in Devices & Printers, then click See what's printing on the command bar. Click the Printer menu, and then click Pause Printing. To resume printing, click Pause Printing again. From the same menu you can also pause and restart individual documents.

To set the printer offline, double-click the icon of the printer in Devices & Printers. The status of the printer will be shown as either "Printer: Ready" or "Printer: Offline". Click on "Printer: Ready" and the Printer menu will appear. Click on "Printer" in the menu bar and tick "Use Printer Offline." This action will change the printer from online to offline. Reverse this to go back online.

Answer (score -1):

I am a computer technician for a University. 
 To "use printer offline" in Windows 7;

Open the start menu, then Devices and printers.

Right click on the printer you want to use offline and select 'See what's printing'

A print queue window will open. Click on the menu item "printer"

A dropdown menu will open with a list of several items.  One will be use printer offline. Click it once.

If you open that menu again it will have a check beside "use printer offline".  Click it again and you will remove the check.

Note: This is not the same as the printer being offline.  That is when the printer and PC have lost communication with each other due to a network error, a sharing error or the printer simply being off.  This is a setting that allows you to hold print jobs in your local PC print queue until you decide to release them.